# Exception when using Apache POI

Tags: java, exception, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI and I am running this code

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = null;

fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("myDoc"));
HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(fs);
WordExtractor word = new WordExtractor(document);
String[] paragraphs = word.getParagraphText();
System.out.println( "First paragraph text: " + paragraphs[0]);
```

It is giving me this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: myDoc (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
```

Now how can I solve this problem.

Comment: The file `myDoc` doesnt exist. Is `myDoc` a variable or did you mean `myDoc.doc`?

Comment: Amazing that a word document file does not have an extension. Does that file exist? Have you tried opening it as such from your drive directly?!

Comment: What is myDoc. Give full path of file.